# How to change android 4.2.2 to android 4.4 in sdk

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I want to **upgrade from android 4.2.2 to android 4.4** so that I can use android 4.4 emulator. How can  I do this?

I need android 4.4 as I want to check an app as how it behaves with android 4.4

Comment: Download the 4.4 image via the SDK Manager and then create a new image in the AVD Manager after the download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From eclipse use Android SDK Manager and without eclipse go to android-sdk-linux->tools and run android